# Cdf of a mixed distribution.

Tags: probability

Looking to solve:

An automobile insurance company issues a one-year policy with a deductible of 500. The probability is 0.8 that the insured automobile has no accident and 0.0 that the automobile has more than one accident. If there is an accident, the loss before application of the deductible is exponentially distributed with mean 3000.
Calculate the 95th percentile of the insurance company payout on this policy.

Let X be exp(3000); cost of repair before deductible

L be loss for insurance company

L= 0 if X<500

L= X-500 if X>500

I wish to calculate the cdf of L.

Let’s assume wlog x>0

I apply law of total probability and get:

P(L<x)= .8+.2[ P(X<500)+ P(X>500)P(X-500<x)]

I then solve P(L<x)=.95 and get x=31590.

The Manuel says the answer is 31590+500= 36590.

is my cdf wrong?  Am i interpreting the question wrong? Why the plus 500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to observe is that, because losses are exponentially distributed, if a loss occurs and is greater than the deductible, then the amount by which it exceeds the deductible is also exponentially distributed with the same mean.  This is a consequence of the memoryless property of the exponential distribution:

$$\Pr[X > x + d \mid X > d] = \Pr[X > x].$$

So in your case, if a loss $X$ is more than $d = 500$, the variable $L = X - 500$ representing the claim payment in excess of the deductible will be exponentially distributed with mean $\mu = 3000$.  Consequently,

$$F_L(x) = \Pr[L \le x] = 0.8 + 0.2 (\Pr[X \le 500] + \Pr[X - 500 \le x \mid X > 500]\Pr[X > 500]),$$ and the conditional probability in the second term is
$$\Pr[X - 500 \le x \mid X > 500] = \Pr[X \le x].$$  This gives us $$\begin{align} F_L(x) &= 0.8 + 0.2\left( 1 - e^{-500/3000} + (1 - e^{-x/3000})e^{-500/3000} \right) \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{5}e^{-(x+500)/3000}.
\end{align}$$

Then solving $F_L(x) = 0.95$ gives $$x = 500(-1 + 12 \log 2) \approx 3658.88$$ as claimed.

Comment: thanks, very clear explanation and caught my mistake